# Finding maximum difference of pair of elements in an array using EXACTLY 1 stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to write a function to find maximum difference between any 2 elements in an array (1D). I have already solved it in several ways (I apply in Java)

1. With *2 nested loops* (works, finds difference and takes the maximum)
2. With *1 loop iteration* (works, finds minimum and maximum after returns difference of them: (max - min))
3. Using *stream twice* (works, finds maximum and minimum with stream's min() and max() functions and return difference).

Now the question is: How to write a function which calculate maximum difference between any 2 elements in an array using **exactly 1 stream**?

Here is the last one I wrote:

```
public static int maxDifference(int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).min().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new) -
           Arrays.stream(arr).max().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Arrays.stream(arr).summaryStatistics()` - it returns you an [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) object which has accessors for min and max.